# Change views Contextual Filter based on select list value

Tags: views, datetime

Using [Event Calendar](https://www.drupal.org/project/event_calendar) Module I displayed dates in a calendar views. Now I have to create a select list with options like

- IST
- CST
- EST
- PST

Changing the values should change the Date displayed in the Calendar.

Now I added four different fields for each time zone and added values to it.

By adding a contextual filter in the views for a specific date field, I could see Calendar with dates marked perfectly. Now I created four different view display for each time zone as a tabbed view.

But I actually require it as select list. (for eg: [Pick Date & Time](http://demo.loopio.com/))